# VB6 File Access on Windows 7

Tags: vb6, windows-7

I installed an old VB6 app that I wrote on Windows 7. The app produces an HTML file and saves it to `Program Files (x86)/{Application}/report.html`.

I then installed a newer version of that app on the same machine and ran the same report. But when I open the new generated `report.html` file, I see the OLD version of that file.

It seems like Windows is keeping the files that were generated from the OLD version of the app and not letting the NEW version of the app overwrite them.

The app is running under Windows XP SP2 compatability mode as an Administrator.

Are there any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 3):

It's probably filesystem redirection at work. Writes to %PROGRAMFILES% get transparently redirected to a per-user location. If you run the app as an administrator, that should disable the redirection.